# HTML not connecting with CSS correctly

Tags: html, css, django, frontend

In my Django project, I attempt connect HTMl to CSS. I have looked online and at other related problems on stack overflow, and still cannot get html and css to link together. I am also a complete newbie to frontend development.

Here's my code (The css file is in the same directory as this file):

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<div id="signuptext" class="pb-0"><span>Sign Up</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
#signuptext {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Error received:

```
Not Found: /accounts/signup/signup.css
```

UPDATE: CHANGE PATH(href):

```
/accounts/templates/users/signup.css
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'signup.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

UPDATED CSS(in main static folder):

```
#signuptext {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

I don't understand this error as my css file is in the same folder as the HTML file.
Does anybody know whats wrong? Thank you.

Comment: is signup.css in /accounts/signup/signup.css?

Comment: @AlexDeCamillo It is yes. Check my original post as I have updated it and changed the href to the full path of the file.

Comment: Is that HTML snippet the static file generated from django? Or is it the template file?

Comment: @AlexDeCamillo It is the template file itself.

Comment: Generally, the template file should reference the directory where you're keeping the files. Take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) to see some documentation on doing so. That link is for the development version but you can change to whichever version you're using on that page.

Comment: @AlexDeCamillo Please check my updated code. I have added a css file in my static folder, and also change my settings.py. This time the error doesn't occur, however the font size doesn't change as expected.

Comment: @AlexDeCamillo My css file is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/accounts/signup/signup.css" type="text/css">
```

Also, use classes, it is better because you can reuse them. Only use `id` when you need to use js.

```
<div class="signuptext" class="pb-0"><span>Sign Up</span></div>
```

css:

```
.signuptext {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```